# Why doesn't Windows' gflags fail to crash with this code?

Tags: c++, windows, debugging

I made the following program:

```
int main() {
    int* p = new int[10];
    delete[] p;
    p[0] = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Then I executed this program with gflags enabled:

```
C:\tmp\Test2\Debug>"C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows\gflags.exe" -p /enable Test2.exe /full
path: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options
    test2.exe: page heap enabled

C:\tmp\Test2\Debug>test2

C:\tmp\Test2\Debug>
```

As expected, the program crashes. Running it with a debugger I can see that it crashes at this line:

```
p[0] = 0;
```

That's what I expected.

However, this program doesn't crash:

```
int main() {
    int* p = new int[10];
    p[10] = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Why doesn't gflags catch this out-of-bounds access? Generally, what kind of heap errors are detected by gflags, and what errors are not detected?

Comment: The list is here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779664%28WS.10%29.aspx  The 'heap tail checking' feature won't work because you forgot to release the memory.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Thanks! Why did you post this as comment and not as answer?

Comment: Meh, it is just link soup.  Feel free to post it yourself.

Comment: @gsamaras I feel like editing just the answer to match the question would be better than editing both to match something else.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @QPaysTaxes.

Answer (score 3):

But this program doesn't crash:

```
int main() {
    int* p = new int[10];
    p[10] = 0;
    return 0; 
}
```

Why gflags doesn't catch this?

Because the `new` operation will often allocate memory more than you want, for memory alignment purpose. If you want to crash this, just use `p[1025] = 0;` or something larger.